# Send an email without backend side in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, email

Is there any way I can send email with Angular 4 without involving backend?

I have tried [formspree](https://formspree.io/) but that did not help.

```html
<form method="POST" 
  action="https://formspree.io/usmansaleem.logicon@gmail.com">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Test Message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send Test</button>
</form>
```

Or Am I implementing it the wrong way?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Please create a demo on stackblitz.com

Comment: Using formspree still involves a backend. Just not yours. Angular cannot send emails on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Angular makes every `form` element a `NgForm` implicitly that manipulates behavior of the form.

You need to set `NgNoForm` attribute to the form.

```html
<form method="POST" ngNoForm
  action="https://formspree.io/usmansaleem.logicon@gmail.com">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Test Message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send Test</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it takes to the validation page where i have to click on i am not a robot checkbox then it send an email :D @zmag